# bootstrap datepicker - highlight first selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I found some fiddle, and updated, mainly to show datepicker as components, without inputs.

http://jsfiddle.net/Luhbzxdn/

The javascript code:

```
// Date Pickers
var month = ("January February March April May June July August September October November December").split(" ");
var now = new Date();
var nowformatted = now.getDate() + " " + month[now.getMonth()] + " " + now.getFullYear();
var dpOptions = {
    format: 'dd MM yyyy',
    startDate: now,
    setDate: now,
};

var i = 0;

    var datePicker1 = $("#date1").
        val(nowformatted).
        datepicker(dpOptions).
        on('changeDate', function (e) {
            console.log("dp1", i++);
            datePicker2.datepicker('setStartDate', e.date);         
        });

var datePicker2 = $("#date2").
        val(nowformatted).
        datepicker(dpOptions).
        on('changeDate', function (e) {
            datePicker1.datepicker('setEndDate', e.date);
        });
```

And i run into trouble,  when i select first date, i see blue highligh, so i can know what day is selected, but if i click second datepicker, first selected date has no highlight anymore. Is there a way to keep those highlighted elements, so user can always see, what he selects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in code HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="first-date" />
<input type="text" id="last-date" />
```

And use this code in javascript:

```
function myDateFormatter (dateObject) {
    var d = new Date(dateObject);
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    if (day < 10) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    if (month < 10) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

    return date;
};


// Date Pickers
var month = ("January February March April May June July August September October November December").split(" ");
var now = new Date();
var nowformatted = now.getDate() + " " + month[now.getMonth()] + " " + now.getFullYear();
var dpOptions = {
    format: 'dd MM yyyy',
    startDate: now,
    setDate: now,
};

var i = 0;

    var datePicker1 = $("#date1").
        val(nowformatted).
        datepicker(dpOptions).
        on('changeDate', function (e) {

  $('#first-date').val(myDateFormatter(e.date));
            console.log("dp1", i++);
            datePicker2.datepicker('setStartDate', e.date);         
        });

var datePicker2 = $("#date2").
        val(nowformatted).
        datepicker(dpOptions).
        on('changeDate', function (e) {
  $('#last-date').val(myDateFormatter(e.date));
           // datePicker1.datepicker('setEndDate', e.date);
        });
```

Comment: yes, looks better, but now features with disabling dates are disabled, i mean: now user can select from 22.04.2016 to 20.04.2016, so first date is larger than second.

Comment: Cool. Works fine. Thanks.

Comment: I'm also wondering, how can i get selected item - for example how can i do something with selected day ? I have to add some html content to clicked day.

Comment: You do not have an input text to store selects dates ?